# Deciding database table architecture

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm very new to Databases and looking forward to develop an application with some advanced functionality.

Here I'm going to have a table with users just like the following one.
[image]

So, in the sports column, value will be the sports the user plays. They will be some ids from the records of sports table.

So my problem is how to store those multiple values in the same row same column ?

Thanks

PS: Please note that I'm a beginner...

Comment: Depending on how you intend to use those values, you could create an array of values and store them in the column that way.

Comment: @The42ndDoctor, that breaks first normal form.  So no, don't do that.

Comment: @Devon That's true. I hadn't thought of that. Good point.

Comment: Date of Birth is better than age

Comment: How do you guarantee uniqueness of the user rows ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to maintain three different tables.

**User:** id, name, age

**Sport:** id, name

**UserSport:** user_id, sport_id

The UserSport table references the primary key (id) of both tables (User and Sport) and contains a separate entry for each sport the user participates in.

The primary key of UserSport should then be a composite key of both user_id and sport_id.  This allows you to have multiple rows for each user and multiple rows for each sport, but a unique combination of both the user and sport.

Comment: This is ideal way of doing this. However, if you like to keep in one row then you can keep comma separated value. But then you have to extract values by yourself whenver in needed in your application code, you will not get output from query.

Comment: @Panther Well, you could search comma separated values using LIKE in your query, but the accuracy may be less than perfect.

Comment: @The42ndDoctor That what we need to do some workaround. Ideally it should be like Devon suggested. Rest one can create his own way, i have done comma separated many times depending on requirement.

Comment: To maintain database normalization, ideally, you should never use a comma list.  However, you could create a separate view if there is a requirement for a comma delimited list.

Comment: Thanks... yup, this answered my burning question :) Thanks everyone

Comment: @Panther.  Well, you might have done CSV many times, but it is still dead wrong.  Sure, anyone can do anything, but it remains dead wrong.  It breaks 1NF, and you cannot search the field (LIKE will tablescan) or use aggregation or prevent duplicates or maintain order.  All **normal** features expected of a database.  You have a Record Filing System.  Sure, anyone can do that.   Devon has given some database capabilities (but not a full relational database).

Comment: @PerformanceDBA as i mentioned doing CSV is a workaround , currect way is using databaase normalization. Some scneario where people just have to fetch value once a day or week and keep in some kind of appllication cache , there they can break these strings in their application side like in java or c# . However keeping normalized table is best design

Comment: @Devon Here, when I'm creating the table, should I add a line to define FOREIGN KEYS to make reference to the primary keys of User and Game tables ?   [Here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51664998/Untitled.png) how I'm currently going to create my `UserGame` table. Should I add foereign keys line as well ?

Comment: Yes, you should have foreign keys for user_id and sport_id in this example.